# has_many association not returning record and belongs_to returning different record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have a two models, let's call them `project` model and `file` model for simplicity.
Among other things, project has a `uuid:string` attribute.

I am declaring my association like this

```
file.rb:
belongs_to :project, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: 'uuid'

project.rb:
has_many     :files, class_name: 'File', dependent: :destroy
```

When I call `file.project` I get a different uuid project returned (with `id` equivalent to `uuid.to_i`)

and if I call `.files` in either `project` I get an empty array

Example:

```
p = Project.last
=> id: 7, uuid: "1abc"

f = File.create(uuid: p.uuid)
f.project
=> id: 1, uuid: "some other uuid"

p.files
=> []
f.project.files
=> []
```

`"1abc".to_i` returns 1, I understand that's why I am getting `project` with id 1, but I need `project` id 7 to be associated.

SQL output when generating an association:

```
project = Project.last
=> {id: 8, uuid: 'something'}
file = File.create(uuid: project.uuid)
(5.1ms)  BEGIN

  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[i18n-debug] es-CL.activerecord.models.file => nil
[i18n-debug] es-CL.activerecord.attributes.file.project => nil
[i18n-debug] es-CL.attributes.project => nil
[i18n-debug] es-CL.activerecord.errors.models.file.attributes.project.required => nil
[i18n-debug] es-CL.activerecord.errors.models.file.required => nil
[i18n-debug] es-CL.activerecord.errors.messages.required => nil
[i18n-debug] es-CL.errors.attributes.project.required => nil
[i18n-debug] es-CL.errors.messages.required => nil
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the generated *SQL* queries of the same?

Comment: @Pavan I have added an example of the behaviour

Comment: Can you create a new project with uuid like a random string that doesn't start with an integer and create its associated file, see if that succeeds

Comment: @Pavan it does not succeed. Probably because `"something".to_i` returns 0 and there ir no Project with id 0

Comment: I'm curios to see the SQL queries that generated in the background. Can you find those and paste them in the question?

Comment: @Pavan ok, I've added some output. Let me know if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding `primary_key 'uuid'` and `foreign_key:'uuid'` to both models, like this:

```
file.rb:
belongs_to :project, class_name: 'Project', foreign_key: 'uuid', primary_key: 'uuid'

project.rb:
has_many     :files, class_name: 'File', dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'uuid', primary_key: 'uuid'
```